# Plotting each subsets of data in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, subset

I have a matrix of m = (50507x11) rows and column and I want to plot column 11 but in subsets of the data.
For example, I want to plot column 11 in sections, 
e.g. plot(m(1:500,11)), then plot(m(500:1000,11)) and so on but in a for loop or whatever loop in matlab.

Anyone has any idea how to do that.

Comment: do you want an array of lines or an array of figures? There are various answers here for both. What have you tried so far? Please intensify your search a little...

Comment: Actually i want arrays of figures of subsets from the data. I tried to search but could not found what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do this:

```
column = 11;
chunksize = 500;
n = floor(size(m, 1) / chunksize);
l = ceil(sqrt(n));
for i = 1 : n
    chunk = m((i - 1) * chunksize + 1 : i * chunksize, column);
    subplot(l, l, i);
    plot(chunk);
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code plots all the subsets in one plot. I need these plots of subsets in separate plots.

Comment: I modified my example accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Your new version with subplot shows an error ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: I overwrite input matrix m. Fixed.